# hardware identification to be open a web page on cliet side

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, security, identity

I have a web page of asp.net using c#.I am now want to implement the hardware security that any hardware identification should be fullfiled before opening the web page.I meant if allow the that hardware of client then it will open the web page otherwise it should make error of authorization etc.Is there anywat to do this that i can detect client hardware identificaions and then allow to open the web page.Plz help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to detect the client hardware directly through the browser.

The `User-Agent` http request header can give some information about the user OS, but still remember that users can modify and send whatever headers they please. Not something you should count on for security.

The web does not allow you to lock users to hardware, and it is IMO a bad practice.

You can at the server keep track of active sessions, and allow only a certain number of sessions per user.